# logback-ext-spring - can't get RollingFileAppender working

Tags: spring, logback, spring-java-config

I implemented Logback in Spring Java Config using the 0.1.4 version of logback-ext-spring. My ConsoleAppender seems to be working.  But while the specified RollingFileAppender log file is created (log.log), and locked while the application is running, it is never written to.

Here is the full class.  As you can see I set it up as a @Configuration, and am autowiring the beans together.  That part seems to be functioning, as I can debug that everything gets wired up just fine.

I am piping the RollingFileAppender to an AsyncAppender, but removing that does not seem to change the results.

```
@Configuration
public class LogbackConfig {

    @Autowired
    private LoggerContext loggerContext;
    @Autowired
    private PatternLayoutEncoder patternLayoutEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private ConsoleAppender consoleAppender;

    @Autowired
    private RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextHolder applicationContextHolder() {
        return new ApplicationContextHolder();
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggerContext loggerContext() {
        return (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    }    

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public PatternLayoutEncoder encoder() {
        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
        encoder.setPattern(".%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n");
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public ConsoleAppender consoleAppender() {
        ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
        consoleAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        consoleAppender.setEncoder(patternLayoutEncoder);
        return consoleAppender;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender() {
        RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
        fileAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        fileAppender.setFile("/logs/spring/log.log");
        fileAppender.setEncoder(patternLayoutEncoder);
        TimeBasedRollingPolicy<Object> policy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<>();
        policy.setContext(loggerContext);
        policy.setParent(fileAppender);
        policy.setFileNamePattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n");
        fileAppender.setRollingPolicy(policy);
        return fileAppender;
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public AsyncAppender asyncAppender () {
        AsyncAppender asyncAppender = new AsyncAppender();
        asyncAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
        asyncAppender.setQueueSize(500);
        asyncAppender.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);
        return asyncAppender;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you get it to work ? I'm faced with a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999436/configure-a-logback-java-based-no-xml

Comment: To see if your config is used at all, comment it and see if the console output changes. Mine didn't. So, not only the file appender, but all appenders were ignored in my case.